# Finding out document template type of document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2003

When I make a document library in Sharepoint 2003 and select the document template type etc. and come back to edit/administer the document library, how can I find out what document template type I selected at the time of creation?

Another way of putting it: If an administrator makes a document library and selects a document template type then leaves without documenting the settings for the document library, how could I find out what document template type was selected?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure whether the [CodePlex SharePoint Manager 2013](http://www.codeplex.com/spm) will work for SharePoint 2003, but it does for 2007. Simply you can try to use Object Model and get the template, that is what SPM does internally.